# Why doesn't my function check for child nodes?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I want to check whether the div element has any children. If it does the function should run the code, if not it should return. Unfortunately, it always runs the code even if there are no child nodes.
Code:

```
function finishOrder() {
    if(wrapper.hasChildNodes()){
        transparentBg.style.display = 'flex'
        body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
        document.querySelector('.pop-up-purchase').style.display = 'flex'
        document.querySelector('.pop-up-price').textContent = document.querySelector('.total-cost p').textContent
        document.querySelector('.close-pop-up').addEventListener('click', closePopUp)
        while(wrapper.hasChildNodes()){
            wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.firstChild)
        }
        totalCost()
    } else{
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should try `.childElementCount` instead of `.hasChildNodes()` since an empty text node still counts as a child node

Comment: If you mean to check whether .childElementCount is bigger than zero, I already tried that it didn't work out

Comment: In that case, it sounds like `wrapper` is not empty, have you tried using `console.log` to check how many childs there are and what they look like? (`console.log(wrapper.innerHTML)`). FYI the if statement could just be `if (wrapper.childElementCount ) {...}`

Comment: Man, I am so stupid! :) I have been using the wrong JS file :). It works almost perfectly now